# JSF application not supporting multiple users logged in

Tags: java, session, jsf

I am a JSF beginner and have developed a mini application that is working fine. the problem is, when more than one user logs in, the application won't work. Only one user can log in and work. what part of application probably have to be checked??? the only static variable in my application are the beans managed name as follows:-

```
 public static final String MANAGED_NAME = "catBean";
 public static final String MANAGED_NAME = "appBean";
```

etc etc. 
Do I need to change the static keyword? or where possibly can error be in my application. this is way too primitive question but owing to my very little knowledge accepted........:)

Comment: As you can see, your constants variable names are identical.

Comment: the two line are from  different classes...

Comment: I think you should provide some more information as to what do you mean by not working with multiple users. Is there any error when multiple users logs in ? How are you maintaining the information realting to user login state ?

Comment: Or you're misinterpreting the results because you're trying to login multiple times inside one and same browser session (e.g. in different tabs) instead of using physically different browser instances (e.g. one Firefox and one Chrome).

Comment: @ Apurv....I m not saving any information regarding state. just give log in page to user and get the user verified from database. on log out. i am resetting a boolean value that is later on used to check whether a user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take sessionScoped bean to maintain session data

It seems you are using static fields which  are shared and they are not at object level they are associated with class